# Comparing two enum variables regardless of their associated values

Tags: swift, enums, compare

Consider this enum:

```
enum DataType {
    case One (data: Int)
    case Two (value: String)
}
```

Swift has pattern matching to compare an enum with associated values, like so:

```
let var1 = DataType.One(data: 123)
let var2 = DataType.One(data: 456)

if case DataType.One(data: _) = var2 {
    print ("var2 is DataType.One")
}
```

**How would one go about comparing not one variable against an enum type, but comparing the enum type of two variables?** I saw a ton of similar questions, but none focused on the case where you have two variables.

What I basically want is:

```
if case var1 = var2 {
    print ("var1 is the same enum type as var2")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated approach:**

I think there's no native support for this. But you can achieve it by defining a custom operator (preferrably by using a protocol, but you can do it directly as well). Something like this:

```swift
protocol EnumTypeEquatable {
    static func ~=(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
}

extension DataType: EnumTypeEquatable {
    static func ~=(lhs: DataType, rhs: DataType) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (.one, .one), 
             (.two, .two): 
            return true
        default: 
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```swift
let isTypeEqual = DataType.One(value: 1) ~= DataType.One(value: 2)
print (isTypeEqual) // true
```

**Old approach:**

```swift
protocol EnumTypeEquatable {
    var enumCaseIdentifier: String { get }
}

extension DataType: EnumTypeEquatable {
    var enumCaseIdentifier: String {
        switch self {
        case .one: return "ONE"
        case .two: return "TWO"
        }
    }
}

func ~=<T>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool where T: EnumTypeEquatable {
    return lhs.enumCaseIdentifier == rhs.enumCaseIdentifier
}
```

The older version depends on Runtime and might be provided with default `enumCaseIdentifier` implementation depending on `String(describing: self)` which is not recommended. (since `String(describing: self)` is working with `CustromStringConvertible` protocol and can be altered)

Comment: You can actually make this a lot better by extracting a raw value using `String(describing: self)` inside the enum and then using that rawValue for comparison. But great idea!

Comment: @NikxDa Not sure, But i think `String(describing: self)` will include associatedValue as well.

Comment: Converting enum case to string just to compare is counter-productive. And string comprising is almost slowest way to compare anything.

Comment: @user28434 it's not for comparing its values, that "WOULD" be counter-productive. OP is asking about comparing cases (which are actually stored as String on the system as well)

Comment: @farzadshbfn, but you're not comparing using system string representation, you're using your own strings and compare them character by character each time. It is counter-productive. The thing is **you don't need string identifiers at all here**. Code in the other question does it just fine without it, and it can be statically optimized by compiler too, your code relies heavily on runtime.

Comment: @NikxDa Using `String(describing: self)` would not be a good idea. Since it can be altered with `CustomStringConvertible`

Comment: @user28434 but the code on the other question does change meaning of `Equatable`. OP wants both Equatable and case Equitability at the same time. If you're problem is with performance, I can make it in way to be more optimized based on usage. (I'll change it in a bit)

Comment: @user28434 I don't think this functionality would be achieved for multiple types at the same time, without Compiler providing this functionality. (just like `allCases` was not possible before swift 4.0)

Comment: @farzadshbfn, yes, as I said in the comment to that answer, that is the only thing wrong with that code. Code itself is exactly what should be done, you should use `switch` with `case`. Just take that code and move it somewhere else. Do not make it slow by using `String`s.

Comment: @user28434 Ok, I'll changed the approach in order for system to be able to optimize it in compile time as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just confirm to `Equatable` like below

```
extension DataType: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: DataType, rhs: DataType) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (.One, .Two), (.Two, .One):
            return false
        case (.One, .One), (.Two, .Two):
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to implement `Equatable` just move content into instance method:

```
extension DataType{
    func isSame(_ other: DataType) -> Bool {
        switch (self, other) {
        case (.One, .Two), (.Two, .One):
            return false
        case (.One, .One), (.Two, .Two):
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

**Use:**

```
let isTypeEqual = DataType.One(value: 1).isSame(DataType.One(value: 2))
print (isTypeEqual) // true
```

Comment: Also you can do `if var1 == var2`

Comment: @Kamran, for the type of equality OP asks **you definitely have to** implement it manually. Default implementation will match using associated values, and *question* asks for a way to compare only case names without minding different associated values.

Comment: @Kamran, what? Can you please read the question, and check in Playground how default `Equatable` implementation behaves, and how it differs from desired behaviour?

Comment: @Kamran That depends on the Swift version. These implementations would not get syntehsized before Swift 4.0

Comment: I don't think making enum conform to `Equatable` like this be a good idea since it is changing the meaning `Equatable` have.

Comment: @SPatel I do not want to use Equatable because I need an in-depth comparison aswell. So basically I need both the default (in-depth) equatable, _and_ a way to just compare the types.

Comment: @NikxDa, you may take function body and move it in some custom `operator` or just some static function. Function body is exactly what you need, where you put it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
enum DataType {
    case one (data: Int)
    case two (value: String)
}

protocol EnumTypeEquatable {
    static func sameType(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
}

extension DataType: EnumTypeEquatable {
    static func sameType(lhs: DataType, rhs: DataType) -> Bool {
        if let caseLhs = Mirror(reflecting: lhs).children.first?.label, let caseRhs = Mirror(reflecting: rhs).children.first?.label {
            return (caseLhs == caseRhs)
        } else { return false }
    }
}

let isTypeEqual = DataType.sameType(lhs: .one(data: 1), rhs: .one(data: 2))
print (isTypeEqual) // true
```